# Complex Sql Query to RoR ORM

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

I have a very complex sql query that I would like to convert to RoR's ORM.

```
SELECT c.* FROM (SELECT companies.* FROM companies WHERE city = "?" AND country = "?") AS c INNER JOIN tagsForCompany AS tc ON c.id = tc.Company INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = tc.TID WHERE t.Name REGEXP '?'
```

I have defined the models like this:

companies.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ... Some code that doesn't matter 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
    # ... Some other code 
end
```

and tags.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :company
end
```

I need a function in the companies controller that searches for the companies like the query above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

**First**: `find_by_sql()`

Description: Allows you to put any query you want on it.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

**Second**: Combination of `.where()` and `.joins()` method.

But be careful, if you call `.joins()` after a `.where()` with a nil return, you will get an error of undefined method. The solution here would be to first test if `.where()` returned anything, then you can join with another table.

Possible ways to use joins:

`joins(:tags)`  Creates a Inner Join

`joins('Left join foo...')` Enables you to use left outter joins

`joins(tagsForCompanies: :tags)` Nested Joins if you have N to N associations.

See API:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Something like this ?

Company.where([city = "?" AND country = "?", "NY", "US"]).joins(:tags).where(t.Name REGEXP '?', '/regexp/')

Take a look at where() method and joins() method:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins

Comment: Also, you should use rails convention of pluralize in : has_and_belongs_to_many :companies

Comment: When a record doesn't exist I get an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `tags' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:58:in `search'

Comment: If you join anything with an empty table, you won't get result. Unless you wanted a left join, which is not the case. So you can first do the where clause, if it returns the value, you join it, otherwise you already now that it won't be any results

Comment: Maybe you will need nested association also. It works like this:
Company.joins(tagsForCompanies: :tags)

Comment: thanks! please put this as answer so I'll approve it.